# Calculating new raster metrics without polygonizing in R?

Tags: raster, r, resolution, aggregation

I have an enormous number of large rasters representing tree canopies. Every individual canopy has a unique number that is assigned to each pixel that is part of the tree. I am working with R and the `raster` package amongs others.

I would like to create a lower resolution raster with some statistics about the trees in each pixel. Originally, I was converting the crowns to polygons, calculating the area and diameter of the crown, and then converting it back to a raster like this:

```
crownsPoly[["crownArea"]] <- area(crownsPoly, na.rm = TRUE)

blankraster <- raster(ext= StudyArea, res = 100)

averageCrownarea <- rasterize(crownsPoly, blankraster, field = "crownArea",
     fun=function(x) {mean(x)}, background = 0, filename = "avcrown", format = "GTiff")
```

This worked well for my small test rasters, but converting larger rasters to polygons overloaded my memory, and I figure skipping that step would be more efficient anyway.

Is there a way to do this calculation without converting into polygons? I thought maybe I could use the `aggregate` function, but I don't know how to write the equation. Somehow I would need to get a sum of pixels with each unique value that fall within a pixel of the new resolution and divide by the total number of unique values that exist within that cell. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Considering a case for instance the original raster has 30m x 30m resolution (pixel size), and we want it be 100m x 100m.

If we can find a common divisor between before-after resolutions (10m in this case) then;

1. **disaggregate()** to refine 30m grid to 3 x 10m grid, then;
2. **aggregate()** to upscale 10m grid to 100m grid.

And the code will be:

```
library(raster)
# A dummy sample 30m x 30m
r0 <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=6, xmn=0, xmx=360, ymn=0, ymx=180, crs=NA, vals=1:(12*6))
# disaggregate() to make small cells (one third)
r1 <- disaggregate(r0, fact= 3, method='bilinear')
# aggregare() to make it big (10 times)
r2 <- aggregate(r1, fact= 10, method='mean')
```